# NullPointerException in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to compare the slot inside the table with the variable `f` to see if there is a repeat or if the slot is empty.

It complies but ends up giving me a `NullPointerException`.

Here is my code, issues are marked with `//this one`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class Journal extends JPanel
    {
    public Journal()
    {
        String colN1 = "Date";
        String colN2 = "Student"; 
        int a = 20;
        int b = 5;
        int c = a*2/b;
        int col = c*2;
        String[] columnNames = new String[col];
        for(int colF = 0; colF < col; colF++)
        {
            if(colF%2 == 0)
            {
                columnNames[colF] = colN1;
            }
            else
            {
                columnNames[colF] = colN2;
            }
        }
        int row = b;
        int d = 1;
        Object[][] data = new Object[row][col];
        for (int row1 = 0; row1 < data.length; row1++)
        {
            for (int col1 = 0; col1<data[0].length; col1++)
            {
                if(col1%2 != 0)
                {
                    data[row1][col1]= "day" + d;
                    d++;  
                }
                else
                {   
                    Integer f = new Integer(1);
                    int col2 = 0;
                    int row3 = 0;
                    boolean rows;
                    for (int row2 = 0; row2 < data.length; row2++)
                    {
                        if(data[row2][col2].equals(null))//this one
                        {
                            rows = true;
                        }
                        else if(data[row2][col2].equals(f))//this one
                        {
                            rows = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rows = true;
                        }
                        col2++;
                        if(col2 >= col)
                        {
                            col2 = 0;
                        }

                        for (int col3 = 0; col3<data[0].length; col3++)
                        {
                            if(f > a)
                            {
                                f = 1;
                            }
                            else if(rows == true && data[row3][col3].equals(f))//this oen
                            {
                                data[row3][col3]= f;
                            }
                            f++;
                            row3++;
                            if(row3 >= row)
                            {
                                row3 = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row4 = 0; row4 < getRowCount(); row4++)
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row4, column);

                    if (o != null)
                        return o.getClass();
                }
                return Object.class;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
    private static void gui()
    {
        JFrame gui = new JFrame();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setTitle("Journal List");
        gui.setSize(700,200);
        gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.add(new Journal());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                gui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: has someone mentioned spaghetti code?

Comment: On a side note, *never* check `.equals(null)`. If the object is null, this will throw an NPE.

Comment: @Chechus That's not spaghetti code as there are no noodles (GOTOs or other perverse flow control). It might be "meatballs on the floor".

Comment: @user2864740: Spaghetti code doesn't necessarily have to mean using GOTOs. It could just as well simply mean code with a kinda obtuse control flow. Whether this code matches that criterion may be a separate question, but it's not as if it cannot be argued. :)

Comment: if{if{}else{if{}else{if{}}}}else{if{}else{}} = your "control flow". Man that's spaghetti, just go to your room and refactor it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `x.equals(y)` if `x` may be `null`, since dereferencing `x` would throw a `NullPointerException` in that case. `x.equals(null)` is no more valid.

What you want is probably something more like this:

```
if((x == null && f == null) || (x != null && f != null && x.equals(f)))
```

This can be preferably be abstracted away as a helper function:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    if(a == null)
        return(b == null);
    else
        return((b != null) && a.equals(b));
}
```

Then, you can simply call `if(equals(data[row2][col2], f))`, and reuse it in other, similar, places.

Comment: From the definition he has, f will never be null so the `f == null` and `f != null` checks are irrelevant. You may want to add something about how constructing an `Integer` instance just to compare is a bit obtuse though.

Comment: @Quirliom: TBH, I didn't read of the rest of the code, and I was almost planning to add a suggestion to read http://sscce.org/ and take it to heart.

Comment: Apparently, we like [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 's now.  Being official SO docs and things.

Comment: Haha, I see. I'll take that to heart. :)

Answer (score 0):

replace `if(data[row2][col2].equals(null))/` with `if(data[row2][col2]==null)/`

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[][] data = new Object[row][col];
    for (int row1 = 0; row1 < data.length; row1++)
    {
        for (int col1 = 0; col1<data[0].length; col1++)
        {
            if(col1%2 != 0)
            {
                data[row1][col1]= "day" + d;
                d++;  
            }
            else
            {   
                Integer f = new Integer(1);
                int col2 = 0;
                int row3 = 0;
                boolean rows;
                for (int row2 = 0; row2 < data.length; row2++)
                {
                    if(data[row2][col2].equals(null))//this one
```

So you do `Object[][] data = new Object[row][col];` that creates an array of `null` objects.  (It doesn't instantiate the objects) Then you try to use it here `data[row2][col2].equals(null)` but you never checked if `data[row2][col2]` is not null.  Since it is null, when you try to .equals on it, you get a null pointer exception.  you have to instantiate 'data[row2][col2]' before you try to use functions it has.